# Match quotes delimited strings in previous match

Tags: .net, regex

I could do with some guidance as to the approach here:

I am using .NET regex syntax in an RegEX workflow action. Anyway, I can use

```
(\[.*\])([A-z]*)
```

to match everything inc the enclosing `[` and `]` below

```
Collection(Edm.String)"},"results":["Cheese","Biscuits","Grapes"]}
```

Now, I need to match all my dinner items delimited by quotes, but excluding the quotes.

Can I do this in a single Regex statement or do I need to do this in stages. Ultimately, I would like populate a collection of the dinner items using the available extract or split functions in my Action.

Comment: that looks like JSON - why are you using a regex?

Comment: Do you need to match everything *and* get the list of dinner items, or do you only need to get the list of dinner items and you don't really need the whole match at all?

Comment: You can [try like this](https://regex101.com/r/dA6lX9/1) by use of [`\G` anchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Contiguous) and grab `$1` matches of first capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are most likely using Nintex regex workflow, you need the matches only.

You can leverage the infinite width lookbehind supported by .NET regex engine:

```
(?<=\bCollection\(Edm\.String\)"},"results":\["(?:[^"]*",")*)[^"]+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5CbCollection%5C(Edm%5C.String%5C)%22%7D%2C%22results%22%3A%5C%5B%22(%3F%3A%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%2C%22)*)%5B%5E%22%5D%2B&i=Collection(Edm.String)%22%7D%2C%22results%22%3A%5B%22Cheese%22%2C%22Biscuits%22%2C%22Grapes%22%5D%7D)

The `(?<=\bCollection\(Edm\.String\)"},"results":\["(?:[^"]*",")*)` requires that the 1 or more non-`"` characters (`[^"]+`) were preceded with a whole word `Collection(Edm.String)"},"results":["` and then zero or more sequences of `"` + 0+ chars other than `"`, then `","`.

For a Nintext *Extract* workflow, use `dictResults` as Output value.

Comment: thanks very much. You are correct office 365 Nintex w/f but I am struggling with this regex syntax. I will try it also with https://regex101.com/ to see if I can understand it better

Comment: Regex101.com does not support .NET regex syntax. Install and use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/ExpressoDownload.htm).

Comment: Btw for my last Regex Extract I outputed to collResults and just picked the first item in the collection. Will try a dictionary var this time.

Comment: Well, that part is actually up to you :) I did not mean to sound categoric at that point.

Comment: Thanks once again. I couldn't face another day with that regex. I would have gone insane. loaded Expresso @westerdaled