# Match Quotes Delimited Multichoice Values

Tags: .net, regex

@Wictor

This question could be a sequel to my previous question

[Match quotes delimited strings in previous match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573284/match-quotes-delimited-strings-in-previous-match)

Anyway a mult-choice (checkboxes) on a form creates the following string values in a Nintex Workflow Action

[X] ELearning [X] Online Payroll ......

```
 {"results":[{"Id":3,"Value":"ELearning"},{"Id":4,"Value":"Online Payroll"}]}
```

### Taking on your previous advice I want

- positive look ahead to start matching after "results"
- Exclude non characters
- Exclude "Id" delimited with quotes so not part of a word
- Exclude "Value"
- Match everything else

This is my attempt to replicate the previous approach.

```
    (?<="results":\["(^"Value")(?:[^"]*",")*)[^"]+
```

As usual it doesn't work and continued staring at Expresso's terse error messages just gives me a headache :-(

Regex needs a government health warning IMHO! 
Help SOS!!!

Comment: I think what you want is a JSON parser, not Regex. This will also have the advantage of making your headaches go away :)

Comment: Sadly no, in the context of Nintex as it provides a Regular Expression Action and and us Devs are obliged to use it.

Comment: Can you post the output that expect based on your example?

Comment: @Ibrahim  what happens is the string value is Split using the regex function and the output is a collection object. I enumerate this to get my values. Ironically, I used the previous example to Split a choice column to get my collection. However, in this case I have lookup mult-choice control on my form as I want to easily expand the user choice options as more services get added.

Comment: I am happy to have a go at answering this but I guess I could just do with a few pointers/hints ;-)